# Youtube-dl doesn't download the playlist

Tags: video, youtube

I'm trying to download [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ez10ADR_gM&index=1&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPNZwz5_o_5uirJ8gQXnhEO)

The download starts normally but then, only the specific video gets downloaded and not the whole playlist. I have downloaded entire playlist in the past but this is a particular playlist the Youtube-dl doesn't seem to download in its entirety. 
I also tried -

```
youtube-dl -i $URL
youtube-dl --yes-playlist $URL
youtube-dl --playlist-start=1 --playlist-end= 35 $URL
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Try with a new version of youtube-dl

Comment: Try using the [playlist URL](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPNZwz5_o_5uirJ8gQXnhEO)

Comment: I think wjandrea is spot-on. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually downloading the video at index 1. Remove the index parameter so you can download the whole playlist. Follow the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ez10ADR_gM&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPNZwz5_o_5uirJ8gQXnhEO)
Don't forget to add --yes-playlist

```
 $ youtube-dl --yes-playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ez10ADR_gM&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPNZwz5_o_5uirJ8gQXnhEO
```